# Spring Boot detects 2 identical repository beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot with Spring Data JPA, there is only one `@SpringBootApplication`. And I have also a repository classes, for example:

```
package com.so;
public interface SORepository {
    //methods
}
```

And impl

```
@Repository("qualifier")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SORepositoryImpl implements SORepository {
   //methods
}
```

The proplem is, when I start the application, I get following error:

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.so.SomeComponent required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - qualifier: defined in file [path\to\SORepositoryImpl.class]
    - soRepositoryImpl: defined in file [path\to\SORepositoryImpl.class]
```

So, as you see, somehow 2 beans of one repository class are created. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does your SORepository extends Spring Data Repository (or something in type hierarchy) ?

Comment: No, that's why I provided it here. SORepository is just a simple interface.

Comment: Do you have somewhere bean SORepositoryImpl defined ? Maybe java config like this @Bean public SORepositoryImpl sORepositoryImpl() { return new SORepositoryImpl(); }

Comment: What about your @Configuration classes? Probably you are creating an instance there (the one with the id "soRepositoryImpl").

Comment: I think that @Slavus might be right: The only way I found to reproduce the issue is to explicitly define a bean with the (bean creation method) name `soRepositoryImpl` but also reference this bean by a not matching name (e.g. `@Bean public String foo(SORepository soRepository)`) nothing will match and there is no best guess for spring.

Comment: No, of course I'm not creating any bean of this class. Impl class isn't used anywhere in project. I can't understand how bean with "soRepositoryImpl" qualifier is created. But 100% that there is no explicit creation of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found the issue.

I just couldn't understand, how Spring creates the second bean (soRepositoryImpl), because I've never told it, neither explicitly nor in config classes. But I figured out that the second bean us created during the instantiation of my another `SORepository` (which is in the different package `com.another` and which extends `JpaRepository`).

So, when Spring tries to resolve all dependencies of `com.another.SORepository` it somehow finds my `com.so.SORepositoryImpl` (which has nothing familiar with `com.another.SORepository` - not extending\implementing, not jpa stuff, only similar names!).

Well it seems like a Spring bug to me, because it doesn't check the real inheritance of dependent classes of repositories, only `name + Impl` (even in different package) suits for him.

The only thing that I should do is to rename `com.so.SORepositoryImpl and that it, no 2 beans anymore.

Thanks everyone for answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Data JPA methods having created Proxy element and than inject it into public class SORepositoryImpl:

```
public interface Proxy() extends JpaRepository<Element, Long>{
     Element saveElement (Element element); //ore other methods if you want}
```

And than:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SORepositoryImpl implements SORepository {

@Autowired
private Proxy proxy;

   //end realisation of methods from interface SORepository 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the @Repository annotation off the SORepositoryImpl class

e.g.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SORepositoryImpl implements SORepository {
   //methods
}
```

The error message is implying you have two beans, one named "qualifier" and one named "soRepositoryImpl", which is probably in a Config class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should share your SomeComponent class supposing you have no extra configuration class/xml. My take is that you are injecting as 'soRepositoryImpl' there where you have defined as 'qualifier'. Having two options them. I would say to just remove the annotation parameter 'qualifier' and it should work.

Moreover, unless you want do specify an custom DAO implementation you can avoid @Repository at all (That's an annotation you use to make it injectable for your services). You can just create an interface extending Spring interface and define methods for queries.

For example:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  List<Person> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(EmailAddress emailAddress, String lastname);
```

Then you can just inject it in your services/controller directly.

```
  private final PersonRepository personRepository;
  public PersonController(final PersonRepository personRepository) {
    this.personRepository = personRepository;
  }
```

check samples:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Comment: There is no extra logic in SomeComponent, just Autowiring of SORepository without any qualifier.

Comment: And of course I know about extending spring interfaces, but in this particular case I want not to extend jpa interface, and using my own implementation instead.

Comment: So didn't work removing the qualifier? do you have any other bean config settings?