# Spring generates two beans of the same instance "MyRepository"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, duplicates, javabeans

i'm fairly 'new' to Spring Boot and need a bit of help with CrudRepositories.

My problem is the following: When I want to start my Spring Boot Application, it starts just fine, creates all the tables in the database, but somehow manages to fail, because Spring creates two beans of the same interface:

Note that my package hierarchy looks a bit different. Spring Boot however is referencing the exact same interface, twice.

```
The bean 'IMyRepository', defined in com.package.IMyRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in com.package.IMyRepository defined in @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on JdbcRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJdbcRepositoriesConfiguration and overriding is disabled.
```

For clarification: *I do not have two interfaces declared wit the same name*, *I do not have any MyRepositoryImpl classes*, *and I do not have multiple projects with the same hierarchy.* (only one: src/main/.../com.(...).IMyRepository)

My Repository interface looks like this:

```
package com.package.api.components.account.repository;

import com.package.api.components.account.entity.Account;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface IMyRepository extends CrudRepository<Account, Long> {

    Account findByEmail(String email);

    Account findByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password);
}
```

And the only *single* time where, I am taking usage of IMyRepository is in this class:

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AccountService implements IAccountService, IRegisterService, ILoginService {

    private final IAccountRepository accountRepository;

    private final IPasswordValidationService passwordValidationService;
    private final AAccountMapper accountMapper;

    // Code
}
```

Here are some answers on StackOverflow & co I've already tried, which none off them worked for me:

- https://coderanch.com/t/747155/java/bean-defined-myRepository
- [Spring Boot detects 2 identical repository beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41123195/spring-boot-detects-2-identical-repository-beans)

Thanks you very much for reading this!

Comment: I would start with removing the `@Repository` annotation first and see if that helps

Comment: @JCompetence Don't I need that in order for spring boot to even recognize this as a CrudRepository / Repository Bean? //Edit: I've just removed all the \@Repository annotations from the repositories and I still get the same error.

Comment: You WILL need the @Repository. Where is your actual reference to the repository, it didn't show in your code clip?

Comment: @jr593 What exactly do you mean by "actual reference to the repository"?

Comment: You dont need the annotation.  Example `public interface MessageRecordRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MessageRecord, Long> {

    Page<MessageRecord> findAllByMessageFlowIn(List<MessageRecord.MessageFlow> messageFlows, Pageable pageable); ` this works fine, and has no annotation :).

The fact that it is still failing for you means, that it is still loading it as a repository even without annotation.  Please show your configuration file + class and.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001275/do-i-need-repository-annotation-when-extending-crudrepository-spring

Comment: @JCompetence which class exactly? And do you mean "application.properties" as the configuration file?

Comment: You have duplication somewhere @Z-100 I would start with commenting out each class and leave the repo on its own and see if it loads it.  If using mvn, clean install before running springboot.  Do you have any `@Bean` definitions anywhere?

Comment: Have you read the error? This indicates you have **both** `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc` on your classpath. Both of which will try to create a repository for the given interface. Decide which to use **or** explicitly tell what to use for that package using either `@EnableJpaRepositories` or `@EnableJdbcRepositories` for that package. But I suspect it is a mistake and you accidentally added `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Probably. I've created my pom.xml with the help of the Spring Boot dependency pop up at the beginning of the project and some more dependencies of my previous projects. I just removed ```spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc``` from the classpath and pom.xml. Now my entities are using javax.persistence.table annotations and the project is not starting. (This time I'm not even getting an error message; Just ```[ionShutdownHook] ... : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'```

Comment: @JCompetence No. I don't have anything defined as \@Bean. I only used ```@Component, @Repository, @Table & @Entity```.

Comment: If there is nothing to keep it running, like `spring-boot-starter-web` it will immediately shutdown. Do you have something like that? Also you don't get an error anymore so that has been resolved, which was your actual question, and related to the inclusion of multiple `spring-boot-starter-data-*` dependencies. Also the `@Repository` is useless on the interface (it only hurts the eyes) as Spring Data uses different means of detecting the repositories needed to instantiate.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you very much! It's working perfectly fine now. But could you answer me one more question? Why exactly does Spring Boot need ```spring-boot-starter-web``` to keep running?

Comment: It doesn't as it depends on what you want to do. A web application has threads that keep running to handle requests. If you don't have something like that, nothing is preventing the shutdown and it will shutdown right after startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments of [@M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum), the problem was, that (in my case) I had two `spring-boot-starter-data-...` dependencies, both of which wanted to create beans of the same class/interface, with the same Impl name.

I solved the problem, by following their instructions:

1. I deleted the dependency `spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc`
2. I also deleted the library from the project and classpath

Another problem was, that my project wouldn't keep running. I, again, solved this problem by following their instructions:

1. I added the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency

Answer (score 1):

Don't put @Repository (or @Component) on the interface, only on the implementation.

Comment: In this, (and other projects) I have never implemented a Repository, as I want it to be automatically autogenerated by Spring Boot. (In an other project, which has the same structure, imports and methods, everything works just fine and my code runs). And as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41123793/14442758), you should do the exact opposite.